# How do you pass Section 508 for a searchbox in HTML 5?

Tags: html, search, input, wai-aria, section508

[508 Standards, Section 1194.22 (a)](http://www.access-board.gov/sec508/guide/1194.22.htm) states that:

> A text equivalent for every non-text
>   element shall be provided (e.g., via
>   "alt", "longdesc", or in element
>   content).

For a searchbox, using

```
<input type="text" alt="Search" value="" tabindex="1" name="s" id="s" />
```

passes the 508 Standards, but doesn't pass HTML 5 validation.

Is using `<label>` tags the only way of passing both the 508 Standards and the HTML 5 validation, because I would like to avoid having an unnecessary `<label>` tag?

Comment: Why do you think the label tag is unnecessary, how else are you providing the information?  The `alt` attribute only works on `img` elements, it's not going to provide any information to screen readers as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The label tag is unnecessary extra space, and the search button already provides the word "Search."

Comment: Is your search button before the input field?  How is a screen reader user to know this is a search field?

Comment: The search button is after the input field. Essentially, it is the search box followed immediately by the search button on the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to page more attention to 1194.22 (n) in this situation.  If you really, desperately need to do without a separate label you could try something like this:

```
<input type="search" value="" tabindex="1" name="s" id="s" />
<label for="s"><input type="submit" value="search"></label>
```

But I would strongly recommend at least trying this out in a screenreader ([NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) is free, [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/downloads/jaws/jaws-downloads.asp) can be used for 40 minutes on a 'free trial') or, even better, setting up a test page and getting some screen reader users to try it.

Alternatively you could [investigate `aria-labelledby`](http://www.marcozehe.de/2008/03/23/easy-aria-tip-2-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/) and see if that allows you to fit in your label more naturally.

Comment: HTML 5 doesn't validate; it says something about the label needing to have the same id as the inner input.

Comment: @mc10 if validation is more of a concern than whether or not it's actually accessible, you could try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Yhs9E/1/)